# jquery gui elements not working on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-app

Experimenting with chrome extensions using jquery to make the gui elements, can't get the jquery gui elements to appear on the html page however... what am I doing wrong?

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "my extension",
  "description": "my first chrome extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js", "js/jquery-1.10.2.js", "js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"], "pages": ["window.html"]
  }
 },
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

window.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Well Hello</title>
<link href="css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="accordion">
<h3>test</h3>
<div>details</div>
<h3>test</h3>
<div>details</div>
<h3>test</h3>
<div>details</div>
<h4>test</h4>
<div>SOME JAZZ GOES HERE</div>
</div>
</body>
```

background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 800,
      'height': 600
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you pasted the wrong thing for your manifest.json... Also what error you getting in the console?

Comment: haha, so I did! no error in the console the jquery gui elements just aren't showing on the page, they work when i just open the page in the browser...

Comment: Note that from your manifest declaration, you're building a Chrome App, not a Chrome extension. You're going to find things confusing if you read the extensions docs and assume they apply to apps (and vice-versa). In many cases they don't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to run inline javascript which is no longer allowed in chrome extensions since manifest version 2. Place your javascript from window.html in a file called window.js and then include it in your scripts.

Extension hierarchy:

```
MyExtension/
  background.js
  manifest.json
  window.html
  window.js
  js/
      jquery-1.10.2.js
      jquery-ui-1.10.4.js
  css/
      jquery-ui-1.10.4.js
      images/
             ....jqueryui images....
```

window.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Well Hello</title>
  <link href="css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
  <script src="window.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3>test</h3>
    <div>details</div>
    <h3>test</h3>
    <div>details</div>
    <h3>test</h3>
    <div>details</div>
    <h4>test</h4>
    <div>SOME JAZZ GOES HERE</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

window.js

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "my extension",
  "description": "my first chrome extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js", "js/jquery-1.10.2.js", "js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"], "pages": ["window.html"]
      }
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 800,
      'height': 600
    }
  });
});
```

For future reference, you can rightclick your launch window and inspect element which would have shown you the inline error. Googling this error message has many results for similar issues.

Comment: thanks for this, still nothing appearing - when you say launch window what do you mean? I'm just experimenting with this in Aptana studio? When creating the window.js and referencing the html file to window.js the jquery gui element don't appear when I view the page in a web broswer? Cheers!

Comment: You manage your chrome extensions from the chrome://extensions tab in google chrome. Beside your extension notice the `Launch` button. When you click this your window.html page pops up, this is what I meant by your launch window. Did you place window.js in the same folder as window.html? It should work, it works for me..

Comment: hi judgeja, still no luck - can you show me the whole structure you have and the jquery file? cheers

Comment: Hey, I added the whole layout there as I have it.. I'm pretty sure you don't need the `"pages": ["window.html"]` bit in your manifest either but I left it in just in case you're using it elsewhere and it's not doing any harm anyway.

Comment: I don't think I've been clear enough on the problem I was having...

https://github.com/toniprada/jqueryUi-chromeExtension-adapter

That describes the problem and solution, thanks for your help though judgeja

Comment: I hadn't included the images folder but of course you need that too for the icons. I don't see why you would need this different stylesheet that you linked. He's talking about content scripts but you're talking about a launch page which will have the extension folder as it's base URL. The only difference I can see it makes is it turns the "dropdown" divs to white. Could you please clarify for future reference so I can know what I'm missing??